# Changed files, submitted pull request, now how to make a bug fix?

Tags: git, github

I've been working on some code in a feature branch.  I recently committed and submitted a pull request, and while waiting for it to be approved a bug fix request has come in.

I can checkout and pull my master branch again and create a bug fix branch from there but won't that overwrite the files I've just submitted in my PR?  How can I manage two separate code flows on my machine, in one repo?

My understanding is that git stash is for uncommitted work and therefore wouldn't do me any good here-- is that the case in fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply continue working on that feature branch, since [github](/questions/tagged/github) pull requests are "alive", meaning, until they are merged they are always tracking the origin HEAD.

If you want another pull request, you can simply create a feature branch out of this previous feature branch and send another pull request. In this case I would add a note saying (depends on #X).

Since you're talking about a bug, it seems the original pull request doesn't make sense without the fix so I would go for the first option I described.

Hope this helps.